# NSValueTransformer + MagicalRecord + Mogenerator

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, nsvaluetransformer

I can't get my NSValueTransformer implementation to get called upon calling save:(NSErrro **) on my ManagedObjectContext.

I've already tried to fix this problem by wring my own ManagedObject-Class and not relying on Mogenerator, without any success.

Here is a screenshot of my entity configuration: 
[image]

Here is my NSValueTransformer-Subclass (non of the breakpoints will be hit): 
[image]

And here is how i create the model and save the context. 
I've also tried to use the MR_create and MR_saveToPersistentStoreCoordinator-Methodes for crating and saving but without any success.

[image]

Why does core data not execute my NSValueTransformer code when saving the entity to the persistent store coordinator?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it's super important that the `NSManagedObjectContext` is directly connected to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. 
There seems to be a difference between using `[NSMangedObjectContext MR_default]` and the following expression:

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_defaultStoreCoordinator];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
```

I've modified the above code so it uses the other `NSManagedObjectContext`, now my `NSValueTransformer` will be hit.

```
Session *session = [self getSession];
[session MR_deleteEntityInContext:context];

session = [Session sessionWithFirstName:firstName surname:surname response:jsonResponse andContext:context];
[context MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:nil];
```

So my problem is solved - in case somebody knows why I can't use `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_default]` I would be very interested!